# FB Application with custom DB

Tags: database, facebook-graph-api, database-connection

2 quick question:

- is it possible to build a Facebook application saving user profile informations (name, surname, phone numners, ecc.) on a external custom database (so, not FB database), obvioulsy after user approval, etc.
- even if the answer of the above question is "no", do you know a way to pull out user profile information for all users who use the FB application and formally agree to give their personal information within the app? I would like to know if it is possible to do that both from a technical pov and legal pov

Comment: Thank you @luschn for your answer, I know that before store users data it's necessary to specify what you are storing, what you will do and so on. 
Unfortunately I am not a developer so it's quite impossibile for me to understand the answers to my questions just reading the developer guide. At the moment my clients are asking me if it's possible to save user profile informations (ok, no phone)on a external custom database and if there are some limits of doing it.
Could you (or other members) please help me?
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

That´s what a privacy policy is for. In general, you should only store data after telling the user exactly what you store, what you do with the data, how long you store it and how he can get his entries deleted from your database.

Btw, you can´t get the phone number. About the technical way, please go to the Facebook docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs